# How to assign specific data to user in Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams

I have a some topic joined to Kafka Streams.

Stream analysis data and put result to another topic "Recommendations".

One recomendation can be assigned to on or more users.

- How to store recommendation in topic? By key in partition `user_id`?
- What if users are million?
- Could customer connects to stream avoiding topic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to store recommendation in topic? By key in partition `user_id`?

Depending on what you are trying to achieve, the key of the message should be the identifier that will be used to group messages in a single partition. Messages with the same key will be placed to the same partition.

---

> What if users are million?

So your `recommendations` topic will have `N` number of partitions right? You decide to use `user_id` as the key of the message so all the recommendations of the same user are inserted to the same partition and this is absolutely fine.

Now I think what you are missing here is that you don't necessarily have to create a 1-1 mapping between users and partitions.

Comment: Could you explain more about: `Now I think what you are missing here is that you don't necessarily have to create a 1-1 mapping between users and partitions.`. How to know which recommendation are assigned to user?

Or you meant to store recommendations data in recommendations topic without partitions keys and filter it on consumer?

Comment: If yes, it will be heavy to consumer filter all tons of data, let's suppose we have 2TB data in topic with all recommendations, so consumer will be filter it long time.

Comment: @AliceMessis What I mean is that one partition can hold all the messages for N different users.